# Github Pages: Request failed with status code 405

Tags: vue.js, express, github, heroku, github-pages

I deploy vue3 project on github pages. And backend is deployed on heroku(expressjs+mysql). When I do a login action(post action) on github pages it shows:

`xhr.js:177 POST https://XXXX.github.io/api/dologin 405`
`createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405`

I set in vue.config.js as below:

```
 .....
  devServer: {
     proxy: {
         '/api': {
            target: 'https://XXXXXX.herokuapp.com',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
              '^/api': ''
            }
          }
    }
```

},

And in backend file I set as below:

```
let port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
app.listen(port,function () {    
   console.log(`Server running at ${port} port`);
});
```

And  in vuex file I write the request like below:

`....`

`return await axios.post('/api/dologin',credentials)`

`....`

I find out that `yarn build` seems can not find vuex js files, so I copy the vuex files into dist folder git push them toghter. I do not know this action is right or not. I do not how to make `yarn build` include vuex js files. My folder tree is like below:
[image]

Comment: `I copy the vuex files into dist folder git push them toghter.` it doesn't worked that way. You have to `yarn build` once and use the builded dist folder. It sounds like you havn't installed vuex correctly. Can you show us your `package.json` and `main.js`?