# How to deploy vuex file with vue3 project

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuex, yarnpkg, vuejs3

I use `yarn build` command to build vue3 project, but I find that dist file does not have vuex files inside. What should do? My project path is like below.
[image]

Comment: So in the `dist` folder > `js` folder -> your vuex functions are not integrated? What did you do to find out? How did you include vuex in your project? ps: notice what happens when you build for production. Nothing of your documents will be as recognizable as in your preview image.

Comment: @wittgenstein Actually, my problem is this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614412/github-pages-request-failed-with-status-code-405`, and I thought the reason causes this problem is vuex file is not conclude in dist folder...